# What UNIX File permissions would be necessary for someone to GCC compile my .C program?

Tags: permissions

I have written a .C program and submit this file to someone in UNIX.  However, I didn't change the permissions for the file, beyond whatever they were when it was created.

I am simply wondering if i royally screwed up, and they will not be able to use gcc to compile the program, and then run a.out.  The permissions were listed as:

```
-rw-------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user running GCC just needs to be able to read the file, e.g. `-rw-------` is OK if the user is the owner, otherwise 3 `r` may be needed (to do it simply).

And if the user needs to store the compiled program in the same directory (most common case), he also needs write permission in this directory.

Comment: But will they be able to with the permissions in listed?... I'm still confused.  I haven't run UNIX on my home computer for about 8 years, so sorry for the noobishness.

Comment: @Musicode It depends. By *submit* I assumed first that the user became the owner (e.g. the file was transmitted by e-mail in an archive), but I've completed my answer for other cases.

Answer (score 0):

Like vinc17 said you only need read permission to compile you .c file.

`chmod 0444 <filename>`

Check the others permissions on: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Symbolic_notation

If you want to execute the .o file you should need execute permissions

`chmod 0111 <filename>`

EDIT: My bad about 777.

Comment: Be very careful with `chmod 777` if there are untrusted users on the machine as it also sets full write permissions. If the other person compiles the program (this was the question), execute permissions will be set automatically by GCC. Note: execute permissions on the executable, not on the .o file.

Comment: I suppose the executable file should be the .o file or? :)

Comment: No, .o files are [object files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file); they are not executable and should not have the execute bit set on them. The executable is either `a.out` (default name) and the name set up by the user, Makefile, etc. And use `chmod 555` instead of `111` on the executable.